# Как реализовать нечто на подобии атрибута title в консоле задач

Tags: javascript, html, webbrowser

[image: Атрибут title для консоли задач]

Случайно наткнулся на такое в консоли на главной странице google, при наведении на CSS переменную, появляеться нечтно на подобии атрибута title. Вопрос как это сделано? Можно ли такое провернуть кроссбраузерно?

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые браузеры (например, Chrome) при наведении на [css переменную](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) в инструментах разработчика покажут всплывающую подсказку с значением данной css переменной. При этом можно где-нибудь в середине значения css переменной вставить комментарий, тогда он тоже войдёт в эту всплывающую подсказку.

Например можно объявить css переменную вот так:

```
--example-var: 1px solid /* some text */ green;
```

Ниже пример аналогичной функциональности. Если найти в инструментах разработчика единственный `div` сниппета и навести курсор на css переменную `--example-var`, то получим такую всплывающую подсказку:

[image]

```css
:root  {
  --example-var: 1px solid /* some text */ green;
}

div {
  border: var(--example-var);
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Вот аналогичный скриншот из инструментов разработчика Firefox:

[image]

Видно, что в Firefox комментарии внутри всплывающей подсказки для css переменной удаляются. Получается, что кроссбраузерно сделать не получится (ну это, вероятно, и сразу было понятно, браузеры могут реализовывать инструменты разработчика как им захочется). Ну и вообще, совсем непонятно, зачем может хотеться сделать это кроссбраузерно...